# How to get a GADErrorCode from a GADRequestError?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, gadbannerview

I have implemented an AdMob banner view ad, and also the `GADBannerViewDelegate` protocol as defined here:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner

So I can use this callback:

```
/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

I can see from the file that defines `GADRequestError` that there is also a `GADErrorCode` enum:
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/google-admob-sdk/blob/master/src/ios/GADRequestError.h

Which is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/api/reference/Enums/GADErrorCode

-

However I am really struggling trying to get the `GADErrorCode` enum object from the `GADRequestError` error object.

-

This is the value of the `GADRequestError` error object when the ad fails to load because the device is offline:

`Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000f46880 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html?sdk=afma-sdk-i-v7.36.0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html?sdk=afma-sdk-i-v7.36.0, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html?sdk=afma-sdk-i-v7.36.0, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html?sdk=afma-sdk-i-v7.36.0, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.}`

Can that be converted somehow into a `GADErrorCode` enum object?

Comment: Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a `code` property(an `Int`) in `GADRequestError` so you can use that to create `GADErrorCode` as below,

```
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    let gadErrorCode = GADErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
}
```

---

Now let's talk about the SDK behavior.

**No Internet Connection before Admob SDK initialization**

When there is absolutely no internet connection and you initialize the SDK with the following command,

```
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511")
```

You will get the same error that you have in your question and the delegate method `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` will also receive this SDK failure error instead of a banner ad failure error. Actually this error(`kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork` `code -1009`) means that you are not even connected to an internet connection. You can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrornotconnectedtointernet?language=objc) for more detail.

So now if you create `GADErrorCode` from this code `-1009`, it will always go to the `default case` wherever you are using it in a `switch` statement. Something as below,

```
let gadErrorCode = GADErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)!
switch gadErrorCode {
case .internalError:
    print( "Internal Error code \(gadErrorCode.rawValue)")
default:
    print( "Unknown Error Code \(gadErrorCode.rawValue)")
}
```

**Output**

```
Unknown Error Code -1009
```

So this was the explanation when SDK is not initialized.

---

**No Internet Connection after Admob SDK initialization OR before banner request**

When you had an internet connection while you made the configure call `GADMobileAds.configure` and the SDK is successfully initialized then you will always get one of the error code mentioned in the `GADErrorCode` enumeration.

To verify this we can easily fail banner loading in following two ways

**1)** You can start your app having an internet connection so that SDK is initialized, then before creating and loading a banner request, just turn off the internet and then call this code,

```
bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

Now, you will get the `error code 2` which is this case `case networkError = 2`
 in `GADErrorCode` enum which states,

> There was an error loading data from the network.

**2)** Comment out below line in your code, connect to an internet connection and run your app,

```
bannerView.rootViewController = self
```

Now you will get `error code 0` which is `case invalidRequest = 0` and the reason for this error is mentioned in the documentation as

> The ad request is invalid. The localizedFailureReason error
>   description will have more details. Typically this is because the ad
>   did not have the ad unit ID or root view controller set.

So, when the SDK is initialized, you will always get a proper `error code` in the `delegate` `didFailToReceiveAdWithError`.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to work out why I was getting a runtime error after using an exhaustive switch statement covering all cases. That explains it!

Comment: @Kamran :  Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?